# python pandas reading excel file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a xlsx file which has headers in column A and values in columns B through Z. How do I use pandas to read the excel file so that it reads the column names from column A and fills those columns with values from columns B through Z.

Right now when I try to read the excel file it uses the top row value in columns A through Z as column names and uses the values in row second and on for filling the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
In [8]: df = pd.read_excel(fn, header=None, index_col=0).T

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
0  col1  col2  col3   col4
1     1    10   100   1000
2    11   101  1001  10001
```

Source Excel file:

[image]